# EF optimize multiple order by select top 1

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework

I have the following Entity Framework query:

```
var queryResponse = await db.DataPoints.GroupBy(x => x.Device).Select(x => new
   {
       lon = x.Key.DataPoints.OrderByDescending(y => y.DateTime).Select(y => y.Longitude).FirstOrDefault(),
       lat = x.Key.DataPoints.OrderByDescending(y => y.DateTime).Select(y => y.Longitude).FirstOrDefault(),
       date = x.Key.DataPoints.OrderByDescending(y => y.DateTime).Select(y => y.DateTime).FirstOrDefault(),
       label = x.Key.Name,

    })
      .OrderByDescending(x => x.label)
      .ToListAsync();
```

Now you can see in my select, I have to get `lon`,'lat', and 'date'. However the way im doing it, I have to `orderby` and select the first one 3 times.   The 'DataPoints' is a very large table.

in C# i would normally do the `orderBy` once and just select the entire object, and then later on break it up into the 3 properties. However in this case I want SQL to return the exact fields.

is there a more efective way to write this query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
var queryResponse =
    (from g in db.DataPoints.GroupBy(x => x.Device)
     let latestDataPoint = g.Key.DataPoints.OrderByDescending(p => p.DateTime)
                            .FirstOrDefault()
     select new
     {
        lon = latestDataPoint.Longitude,
        lat = latestDataPoint.Latitude,
        date = latestDataPoint.DateTime,
        label = g.Key.Name
    })
    .OrderByDescending(x => x.label)
    .ToList();
```